# Erlang compare two binary file line by line

Tags: erlang

I tried to compare difference from two binary file, but get confused to compare line by line when reading the file. Like read the first line in the both files, then compare, then read second line of both files to compare

```
read(B1,B2) ->
    {ok, Binary} = file:read_file(B1),
    X=[binary_to_list(Bin)||Bin<-binary:split(Binary, [<<"\n">>], [global])],
    {ok, Data} = file:read_file(B2),
    Y=[binary_to_list(Bin)||Bin<-binary:split(Data, [<<"\n">>], [global])],
    compare(X,Y).

compare(X,Y)->
    C3=lists:subtract(F1, F2),
    io:format("~p~p",[C3,length(C3)]).
```

Comment: You can use pattern matching to compare two binaries.

Comment: but I also need to display different values

Comment: Do you want to display difference between two binaries,too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists:zip() to join the two lists into a single list of `{Xn, Yn}` pairs (check that their lengths are the same first), then lists:foreach() on the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more details about what you want to do and what you have tried so far.

I join an example of code that performs the comparison, prints the different lines with the line number, prints the remaining lines if one file is longer.

I do not transform binaries to list, it is unnecessary and inefficient.

```
-module (comp).

-export ([compare/2]).

compare(F1,F2) ->
    {ok,B1} = file:read_file(F1),
    {ok,B2} = file:read_file(F2),
    io:format("compare file 1: ~s to file 2 ~s~n",[F1,F2]),
    compare( binary:split(B1, [<<"\n">>], [global]),
             binary:split(B2, [<<"\n">>], [global]),
             1).

compare([],[],_) ->
    io:format("the 2 files have the same length~n"),
    done();
compare([],L,N) ->
    io:format("----> file 2 is longer:\n"),
    print(L,N);
compare(L,[],N) ->
    io:format("----> file 1 is longer:\n"),
    print(L,N);
compare([X|T1],[X|T2],N) -> compare(T1,T2,N+1);
compare([X1|T1],[X2|T2],N) ->
    io:format("at line ~p,~nfile 1 is: ~s~nfile 2 is: ~s~n",[N,X1,X2]),
    compare(T1,T2,N+1).

print([],_) -> done();
print([X|T],N) ->
    io:format("line ~p: ~s~n",[N,X]),
    print(T,N+1).

done() -> io:format("end of comparison~n").
```

a small test:

````
1> c(comp).                                                  
{ok,comp}
2> comp:compare("../doc/sample.txt","../doc/sample_mod.txt").
compare file 1: ../doc/sample.txt to file 2 ../doc/sample_mod.txt
at line 9,
file 1 is: Here's an example:
file 2 is: Here's an example (modified):
at line 22,
file 1 is: ```
file 2 is: ```
----> file 2 is longer:
line 23: 
line 24: Extra text...
line 25: 
end of comparison
ok
3> comp:compare("../doc/sample.txt","../doc/sample.txt").    
compare file 1: ../doc/sample.txt to file 2 ../doc/sample.txt
the 2 files have the same length
end of comparison
ok
4>
````